CSS - Can you create a div that overlaps the parent div, while the parent is set to overflow:auto?
I have a scrollable div, where overflow is set to auto.
Within that div, I have items that I would like to extend outside the borders of the scrollable parent div.
If I have the scrollable div set to overflow:hidden, position:relative, and the child div set to position:absolute, this works no problem, but once I set the scrollable div to overflow:auto, the scrollable div just scrolls further to contain the child div.
Also, if I set the child div to position:fixed, it overlaps the parent div, but when I scroll, the child div does not scroll.
Is there any way I can achieve what I am looking to do?
Thanks

Yes you can achieve the desired output by the help of z-index property of CSS.
More specifically using a higher z-index value on the child div than that of the parent div. Moreover, adding a container div is also big help in this case.
Try this:


const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const child = document.getElementById('child');

parent.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let scrollPosition = parent.scrollTop;
  let margin = scrollPosition + 'px';

  child.style.marginTop = margin;
});
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  right: -1rem;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: skyblue;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent" id="parent">
    Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent
    Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br> Parent Content <br>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="child"></div>
</div>




Thank you for your response.
Your answer almost answers what I am looking for, but I need that "child" div to also scroll with the "parent", while still overlapping.  Do you know if this is possible?

to achieve that you might need to use javascript, let me provide the code in my answer
